# Reversing a string - output skips last character

Tags: c

I've created this code but it doesn't work well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 5

main()
{
    char arr[MAXLINE] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    int i;

    for(i = MAXLINE; i > 0; i--){
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
 edcb
```

I don't know why it prints a blank before the character 'e', and also it doesn't print the character 'a'.

Moreover if i write the code like this it works perfectly (and I don't know why):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 5

main()
{
    char arr[MAXLINE] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    int i;

    for(i = MAXLINE-1; i > -1; i--){
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Indexing in C starts at 0 and ends at `MAXLINE-1` (in your case).

Comment: In the first code-snipped all you have to do is change `i = MAXLINE; i > 0` to `i = MAXLINE-1; i >= 0` because you want to go to 0 and not to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C array are 0 indexed.

using for(i = MAXLINE; i > 0; i--)

i will be 5,4,3,2,1

```
arr[5] = some character after the arr array 
arr[4] = e
arr[3] = d
arr[2] = c
arr[1] = b
```

From your while loop, I > 0, you never do I=0, so never get arr[0]

for(i = MAXLINE-1; i > -1; i--){

i will be 4,3,2,1,0

```
arr[4] = e
arr[3] = d
arr[2] = c
arr[1] = b
arr[0] = a
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an indexing problem.

In the first block you are trying to index by the length, which is bad.  The reverse character of the the first character has an index of LENGTH - 1.

Also, you will never print out the first character in the first block because your termination condition is ( >0 ).  But your first character has an index of zero.

All you need to do to make the first block work is index by [i-1] instead of [i].